# Reclassifying rasters to two values (1 and NODATA)?

Tags: arcpy, raster, reclassify, nodata

I am trying to reclassify a bunch of rasters, but when I run my script arcGIS crash.
What I want to do, is reclassify rasters this way: every accepted value (0,1,5 and 64) to 1, and the others values just assign "NODATA". By this way, every processed raster would be like a binary raster, just values 1 and "NODATA". The value 1 is because I need to multiply this raster with other raster, acting like a mask. Maybe, I need to reclassify to logical raster (TRUE/FALSE values).

I suppose this problem is caused because every raster could have or not all accepted values, so when I run my script, the actual raster perhaps don't have one of the accepted values, so it crash.

My script is this:

```py
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:/Data/modis_arc/processed/CHL3"
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
for raster in rasterlist:
    clt_name = os.path.join("C:/Data/modis_arc/processed/CHL3/reclass2/", raster)
    outReclass1 = Reclassify(raster, "Value", RemapValue([[0,1],[1,1],[5,1],[64,1]]), "NODATA")
    outReclass1.save(clt_name)
```

Comment: Please provide the error message you receive when the script crashes.

Comment: @jamesslc No error message, just arcGIS crash, the program close completely. I have to restart again. I have to say that arcGIS is working ok,  I have done other task perfectly.

Comment: It might be helpful to put your code in a try/catch block. See python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) or a python wiki [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions).

Comment: Wouldn't expect it to cause a crash, but do you check out the sp analyst extension?

Comment: Could be naming, remove .tif from name and try with grids. Make sure it does not create illegal name for grid

Comment: Hi guys @felixip, I dont think sp analyst extension is working wrong, and the names neither, because when I give the same procedure but "NODATA" included, it works fine. The problem is that I need "NODATA" instruction. I mean, outReclass1 = Reclassify(raster, "Value", RemapValue([[0,1],[1,1],[5,1],[64,1]])) WORKS FINE, but outReclass1 = Reclassify(raster, "Value", RemapValue([[0,1],[1,1],[5,1],[64,1]]), "NODATA") DONT WORK.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a simple conditional instead of reclassify:

```
for raster in rasterlist:
    clt_name = os.path.join("C:/Data/modis_arc/processed/CHL3/reclass2/", raster)
    outReclass1 = Con((Raster(raster) == 0) | (Raster(raster) == 1) | (Raster(raster) == 5) | (Raster(raster) == 64), 1)
    outReclass1.save(clt_name)
```

If raster value is 0, 1, 5, or 64 it will return a value of 1, otherwise it will exclude pixels (no data)

Comment: use "outReclass1 = Con((Raster(raster) == 0) | (Raster(raster) == 1) | (Raster(raster) == 5) | (Raster(raster) == 64), 1, 0)" if you want to have a binary system (0 = no data)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteoutput=True
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:/rubbish"
aList=[0,1,5,64]
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
for raster in rasterlist:
    clt_name = os.path.join("C:/rubbish/output/", raster)
    rr=arcpy.Raster(raster)
    rList=[]
    for n in aList:
        m=Con(rr==n,1,0)
        rList.append (m)
    outCell = CellStatistics(rList, "SUM")
    i=int(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(outCell,"MAXIMUM","#")[0])
    if i>0:
        arcpy.AddMessage('%s converted' %clt_name)
        outReclass1=Con(outCell==1,1)
        outReclass1.save(clt_name)
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage('%s can be saved, but will look weird' %clt_name)
```

Your guess was correct, if no number in list, it produces invisible raster with massive number, which is actually NODATA value = 2147483647. Thus no worries, remove last condition. I even think that your original solution might work if you convert raster (that is string) into raster using arcpy.Raster(raster)

Comment: Hi @felixip, First, I try to run your code but it takes so much time...i suppose because my image size; besides, I have to process >500 images, so it is not useful to me. Second, I changed raster by arcpy.Raster(raster) to my original code, but I continues crashing the system. Thanks, I appreciate your effort and ideas.

Comment: I think you should update your Q with all these complications.